# Oracle Warning message while executing it in SQL Plus

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

When I run the SP in SQL Developer then I am not getting any error.But when I run the below SP in SQL Plus then I am getting 
'Warning: Procedure created with compilation errors.' message

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE P_IGNORE_VENDORS(i_ext_mfg IN varchar2,i_ext_mfg_code IN    varchar2,i_int_checkout_id IN varchar2,i_file_name IN varchar2,i_int_data_source_num IN varchar2, o_status IN OUT varchar2) 

AS
v_counter number :=0;
BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(1) INTO v_counter  
      FROM lu_vendor_complete 
     WHERE ext_mfg              = i_ext_mfg
       AND ext_mfg_code         = i_ext_mfg_code
--       AND row_no                 = i_row_no
       AND int_checkout_id      = i_int_checkout_id
       AND file_name            = i_file_name
       AND int_data_source_num  = i_int_data_source_num
       AND int_data_source_num  = 100000;

END P_IGNORE_VENDORS;
/
```

Any reason for this issue.

Comment: what is the result when you remove the blank lines and try to execute it SQL*Plus?

Comment: You'll see the *reason* if you - immediately after running that code - issue `show err` at the SQL*Plus prompt.

Comment: After removing the space at the end, it worked... Thanks Tejash